# Acces 3D Matrix with 2D index and 1D vector

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a 3D matrix `A` `(size m*n*k`) where m=latitude, n*longitude and k=time.
I want only specific values from first and second dimension, specified by a logical matrix `B` (`size m*n`), and I want only the timesteps specified by vector `C` (`size k`).

In the end this should become a 2D matrix D, since the first two dimesions will colapse to one.

What is the most easy approach to do this?
And also is it possible to combine logical with linear indizes here? For example B is logical and C is linear?

Sample code with rand:

```
A=rand(10,10,10);
B=randi([0 1], 10,10);
C=randi([0 1], 10,1);
D=A(B,C) %This would be my approach which doesnt work. The size of D should be sum(B)*sum(c)
```

Another example without rand:

```
A=reshape([1:27],3,3,3);
B=logical([1,0,0;1,0,0;0,0,0]);
C=(1,3); %get data from timestep 1 and 5

D=A(B,C);%What I want to do, but doesnÄt work that way

D=[1,19;2,20];%Result should look like this! First dimension is now all data from dimesion 1 and 2. New dimesion 2 is now the time.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = rand(4,4,4);
B = randi([0 1], 4,4)
B =
     1     1     0     1
     1     0     1     1
     0     0     1     0
     1     0     1     1

>> C = randi([0 1],1,1,4);
>> C(:)
ans =
     0
     1
     1
     0
```

Then use `bsxfun` or implicit expansion expansion whith `.*` if newer Matlab version to generate a matrix of logical for you given coordinates.

```
>> idx = logical(bsxfun(@times,B,C))

idx(:,:,1) =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0  
idx(:,:,2) =
     1     1     0     1
     1     0     1     1
     0     0     1     0
     1     0     1     1    
idx(:,:,3) =
     1     1     0     1
     1     0     1     1
     0     0     1     0
     1     0     1     1    
idx(:,:,4) =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Then your output is `D = A(idx)`.  However, note that this `D` is now an Nx1 array.  Where N is number of true elements is B times number of true elements in C.  10x True in B and 2x True in C:

```
>> size(D)

ans =

    20     1
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it is to first [reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) `A` into an `m*n`-by-`k` matrix, then do your [indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html):

```
result = reshape(A, [], size(A, 3));
result = result(B, C);
```

In this case `C` can be either a logical vector or vector of indices.